# add class in the child element on the .hover effect

Tags: jquery

i want to add a class name in a input field but don't know the all logic of jquery.
html code is

```
<tr class="jp_contact"><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td><input name="in_val" ></td></tr>
<tr class="jp_contact"><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td><input name="in_val" ></td></tr>
<tr class="jp_contact"><td>text</td><td>text</td><td>text</td><td><input name="in_val" ></td></tr>
```

cod is :

```
$('.jp_contact').each(function(e){
        var currentRow = $(this);
        $(this).hover(
            function(){
                    $(this).addClass('jp_hover');
                    $(currentRow + " td:last").removeClass('dis_button');
                },
            function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('jp_hover');
                    $('input[name="in_val"]').addClass('dis_button');
                });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. On hover, you remove the `dis_button` class from the last cell of the current row. When hovering out, you add a `dis_button` class to a non-existent input element.

Also, you cannot use jQuery objects in a string context. `$(currentRow + " td:last")` should be `$("td:last", currentRow)` (short for [`$(currentRow).find("td:last")`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)).

```
$('.jp_contact').each(function(e){
    var currentRow = $(this);
    $(this).hover(
        function(){
                $(this).addClass('jp_hover');
                $("td:last", currentRow).removeClass('dis_button');
            },
        function(){
                $(this).removeClass('jp_hover');
                $("td:last", currentRow).addClass('dis_button');
            });
});
```

Comment: again thanks sir, the problem is solved with the '$(currentRow).find('input[name="in_val"]'))'